# Android App crashes on Release Build with the use of Proguard and Dagger

Tags: android, proguard, runtimeexception, dagger

I'm new to the use of Proguard and Dagger for Android apps, so I would really appreciate if someone could give me a few pointers.

Proguard and Dagger have been implemented into the application. When the app is installed through debug mode (ie, pushed from Eclipse) there are no problems with running the app. However, when I run the release build of the app, it crashes with the following trace:

```
No injectable members on com.example.test.d. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.example.test.d com.example.test.SampleActivity.a
No injectable members on com.b.a.b. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.b.a.b com.example.test.SampleActivity.b
    at dagger.internal.h.a(ThrowingErrorHandler.java:34)
    at dagger.internal.Linker.a(Linker.java:136)
    at dagger.d.a(ObjectGraph.java:264)
    at dagger.d.a(ObjectGraph.java:238)
    at com.example.test.SampleApplication.a(SampleApplication.java:24)
```

I have followed the suggestions from: https://plus.google.com/108620120050432268974/posts/AAjvwg3Hmgg, by implementing the following into the proguard-project.txt:

```
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.Binding
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.StaticInjection
```

but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard and dagger (pre)-compilation do not seem to work well together in release builds. See  https://plus.google.com/117210567825404150882/posts/HGjnJJHbfMj

The "problem" is that the non-obfuscated package names will be compiled into the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this into the proguard config file ?

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18109765/654026 just in case it helps you out. There you'll see some details on proguard configuration for my app that allowed me to skip app crashes when using Dagger.