# Using proguard with dagger 1.2.2

Tags: android, proguard, dagger

Is there any shortcut (I know, I know, I shouldn't be asking for a magic bullet) to getting dagger 1.2.2 to work with proguard?

We're having issues at the moment, and we know that we have to move over to Dagger 2.0 in order to get proguard working, from this question

[Dagger + Proguard obfuscation, Errors creating object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951753/dagger-proguard-obfuscation-errors-creating-object-graph)

However, ObjectGraph no longer exists in Dagger 2.0 so before we sit down and do a moderate sized refactor, I was just wondering if there was any ignore rule I could put in my proguard file in order to get this to compile in the super short term?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [Dagger Proguard Helper](https://github.com/idamobile/dagger-proguard-helper) library that leverages Java Annotations processing.

Answer (score 2):

For Dagger, you need to keep the generated classes:

```
-keep class **$$ModuleAdapter
-keep class **$$InjectAdapter
-keep class **$$StaticInjection
```

Unfortunately, you also need to preserve the corresponding base classes from your project:

```
-keep class com.example.SomeClass
```

That way, Dagger can still combine the corresponding pairs of classes. You can figure out the base classes by listing the generated classes in the gen directory of your project (e.g. com/examples/SomeClass$$ModuleAdapter.class).

Finally, you need to preserve one Dagger class:

```
-keep class dagger.Lazy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#-dontobfuscate
-keepnames class your.package.**
```

The big problem is that dagger 1.2.2 creates strings like "method/your.package.YourClass", which are not altered by -adaptclassstrings

This will let you run obfuscation along with your build, plus what other folks added about keeping classes in other answers.

You won't be obfuscating your class names, but fields and methods will.  Better than nothing! Or you can disable obfuscation everywhere, just use shrinking.