# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Hi all I want to use ObjectGraph in android I am using following

```
applicationGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
applicationGraph.inject(this);
```

But it gives me error as :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.my.mynews.app.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.my.mynews.b.b could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.my.mynews.b.b could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
        at a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.x.b(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.z.a(Unknown Source)
```

my build.gradle is like:

```
configurations {
 apt
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.0.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
//provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.+'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0'

compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

If I uncomment provided in above dependencies and comment apt and make `minifyEnabled false` then it works perfectly. But I want to reduce code size therefore I have done `minifyEnabled true` and application crashesh.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem myself. Unfortunately, Dagger 1.2+ does not appear to play nicely with proguard's minifyEnabled. So the best options I could find are:

1. Set minifyEnabled false and just deal with it
2. Upgrade to Dagger 2.0 (here's a guide: http://frogermcs.github.io/dagger-1-to-2-migration/)
3. Some people have had luck downgrading to Dagger 1.0.1 and eliminating dagger-compiler altogether (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954164).