# How do I add an unknown amount of unknown modules in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have several modules that I don't know at compile time (think "plugins"). They all implement a "tag" interface `MyModule`: `public interface MyModule {}`

I've instantiated them thanks to `ServiceLoader` and `@AutoService`.

How do I add them all to my component builder?

The Dagger 2 authors [seem to think](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/474) that this question is relevant to StackOverflow. I don't believe that it is, because it looks like a missing use case, but well, I give them the benefits of the doubt here and post it.

I know I could use Guice or Dagger 1, but as said in the ticket to the Dagger 2 team; I don't want any reflection (bar `ServiceLoader`), and Dagger 1 is now deprecated. Also, recommends switching to Dagger 2 (which is why I'm trying to upgrade my Dagger 1 project to Dagger 2).

Comment: Do the modules all provide the same kind of objects to a set or map? Is it expected to be dependencies _between_ the modules? (one module depending on bindings declared in another) To me, it looks like your choice of defining plugins by a dagger module was a bad decision and should be refactored with a clear/clean plugin API (possibly using `@Component(dependencies=PluginDeps.class)` in plugins to depend on things exposed by the app; then reinjecting the plugins into a Dagger graph by passing them to a module in a new component).

Comment: IOW, I feel like you'd rather rethink your problem **not** in terms of Dagger (just one possible solution, or maybe not).

Comment: The plugins need access to injected objects. Yes, there is dependency between some plugins. It worked fine in Dagger 1. I've used a similar principle in Guide. I don't see why the plugin use-case has been thrown in the bin.

Comment: The hooks are in Sets, yes.

Comment: Do they need access to injected objects, or do they need access to arbitrary unknown injected objects.  Since components are, themselves, provided to injection points, it's entirely possible to setup a clean plugin API that supplies services to plugins, and have a    `@Provides @ElementsIntoSet Set<MyPlugin> scannedPlugins(PluginAPI api) { /* do ServiceLocator lookup and initialization */ }` or inject the overall app component itself into the method, and make hte Plugin initialization mechanism take in that information.  I've started to do that in the MOE tool.  Not all there, but promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible as it stands, and is also [outside of Dagger 2's charter](http://google.github.io/dagger/). See the opening sentence of the project overview (emphasis mine):

> Dagger is a **fully static, compile-time** dependency injection framework for both Java and Android.

When you're asking for your object graph to handle arbitrary marker-interface modules, you're precluding Dagger from knowing which @Provides methods it will have access to, which deprives Dagger of the ability to inspect and wire up your component at compile time. So, for Dagger to support your use case *as you've stated it*, it would have to reverse a number of core architectural decisions and advantages of compile-time inspection and code generation. Though I'm not on the Dagger team, I imagine this would make it a poor fit for the foreseeable future, which I imagine is part of the reason your issue was marked Working As Intended.

That said, there are number of ways you could use multiple coexisting components (one per plugin) to use static analysis and code generation in the core application, while supporting an arbitrary number of plugins. For instance, if your plugins have a predictable set of dependencies, you can create a `new PluginModule(PluginFactory... factoriesToSupport)`, which would offer a `@Provides Set<Plugin> createPluginSet(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2)` to iterate across the plugin factories and return you a set of plugins. In addition, if the plugin dependencies represent a large proportion of your top-level Component and your build graph supports it, you could inject the Component itself into the @Provides method, and then let your individually-built PluginFactory instances defer to their own (static-analyzed code-generated) Dagger components to produce the plugin instances. In short, as long as you're in Dagger, you'll need to play by Dagger's compile-time analysis rules, but within those constraints you can still likely come to a workable solution.

Comment: The solution you suggest (`PluginModule`) doesn't allow me to provide my core objects to my plugins if they need them as parameters. What I don't get is the radical change between Dagger 1 and 2 for (what I consider) a minimal gain: the performances are excellent with Dagger 1 and aren't really improved with Dagger 2. This is a kind of incompatibilities I don't expect when being forced to move from version 1 to 2 ("forced" because Dagger 1 is deprecated since September 15). I need a few days to totally process this, before I give my check.

Comment: @Olivier By making your component (or a subset thereof) accessible through `@Provides` method parameters, you _can_ provide those core objects, with the caveat that they may need to be made available explicitly on an interface and propagated through a component dependency. I'm in no position to debate the merits of Dagger 2's compatibility-breaking changes in this comment box, but I will say that performance is not necessarily the only factor; [Dagger 2 is more resilient in an obfuscated/optimized environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23959489/1426891), for instance.

Comment: I understand and I thank you for your valuable input. The incompatible handling is a dealbreaker if I understand your suggestion correctly (providing *all* the dependencies as parameters of a single interface method). At the moment, I'm strongly thinking about forking Dagger 1 internally, with all the consequences it implies. We'll have to discuss this internally because it changes our entire structure (and what I read contains stuff I don't like, from what I understand).

Comment: If there were only a couple of dependencies, I'd advocate passing them individually, but all Components are able to inject themselves. I was saying that your Plugin could come from its own Component with a [component dependency](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) on your app component, so Dagger could still take care of wiring it up.

Comment: And as an original dagger author, @jeff-bowman I concur with your analysis. There are tricks (`@Provides @ElementsIntoSet` with a cleanly designed plugin environment API), but the graph itself is static, and needs to be known at compile-time, both for whole-graph validation, but also because the contrary would require reflection, and that entirely defeats the point.

Comment: We've decided to stick with Dagger 1 for the moment, while migrating to a Plugin API. But this doesn't make your answer less valid. Thank you for the time spent explaining all this.